# Construct std::thread as local object inside a function

Tags: c++, multithreading, object, std

In C++, I want to start a `std::thread` inside a function, like

```
void aFunction(void) {
  std:thread aThread(/*some other function to run inside the thread*/);
  aThread.detach();
  return;
}
```

Since now `aThread` is a local object, I would assume it gets destroyed when `aFunction` returns - but what happens if the process inside the thread is still running?
Can something like this cause any problems?

Comment: [`std::thread::detach`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach): "_Separates the thread of execution from the thread object, allowing execution to continue independently. Any allocated resources will be freed once the thread exits.

After calling `detach` `*this` no longer owns any thread._" - There's even an example in the link doing what you asked for.

Comment: `detach` explicitly asks to "leak this thread". It's use usually signals a problem with the software design. But returning from the function will work as intended. So, you will probably eventually encounter problems but not the ones you seem to be asking about now.

Comment: Why not wrap it in a `std::future` and return it?

Comment: Re, "the process inside the thread." I know it's confusing, but at least you can be confused in the same way as everybody else if you use the same words as everybody else. (1) Don't say "process" here. "Process" means something else.  (2) The thing that you're trying to describe _is_ the thread. Some people say "OS thread" to distinguish it from the `std::thread` object.  A `std::thread` is _not_ a thread. It's an object with methods that let you _create and manage_ a thread.